# How to give domain for lot_id based on product_qty field in odoo 15

Tags: python-3.x, linux, odoo, odoo-15

how to give domain for Lot_id many2one function based its product_qty is more significant than zero (stock.production.lot). product_qty field is a computed field how can I solve

```
lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', string="Item")
```

I need to get lot_id while the Quantity is more significant than zero

Answer (score 0):

Since product_qty is a computed field, you'll need to define a related field that depends on product_qty and use that field in the domain.

```py
from odoo import fields, models

class MyCustomModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'mycustommodel'

    lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', string="Item",
                             domain="[('lot_product_qty', '>', 0)]")
    lot_product_qty = fields.Float(related='lot_id.product_qty', string="Lot Product Quantity")
```

Comment: I tried This method But it not working because the product_qty field is a computed field. That mean it not stored in the Databse

Comment: When giving a domain like this the system shows an error like Unsearchable field 'product_qty' in path 'product_qty' in the domain of field 'lot_id' ([('product_qty', '>', 0)]))

Comment: Can you re-define product_qty: product_qty = fields.Float(compute='_compute_product_qty', string='Product Quantity', store=True)

Comment: Ok, i have changed my answer, by adding a new related field, which can be used in the domain